# Comparing three arrays & get the values which are only in array1

Tags: powershell

I want to find all elements of an array a1 which items are not a part of array a2 and array a3.

For example:

```
$a1 = @(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
$a2 = @(1,2,3)
$a3 = @(4,5,6,7)
```

Expected result:

```
8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $a2AndA3 = $a2 + $a3
 $notInA2AndA3 = $a1 | Where-Object {!$a2AndA3.contains($_)}
```

As a one liner:

```
$notInA2AndA3 = $a1 | Where {!($a2 + $a3).contains($_)}
```

Answer (score 3):

[k7s5a's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6945390/k7s5a) is **conceptually elegant and convenient**, but there's a *caveat*:

It **doesn't scale well,** because an array lookup must be performed *for each `$a1` element*.

At least for larger arrays, PowerShell's **[`Compare-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) cmdlet** is the better choice:

**If the input arrays are ALREADY SORTED**:

```
(Compare-Object $a1 ($a2 + $a3) | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=').InputObject
```

<sup>Note:

* `Compare-Object` doesn't *require* sorted input, but it can greatly enhance performance - see below.

* As [Esperento57](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735690/esperento57) points out, `(Compare-Object $a1 ($a2 + $a3)).InputObject` is sufficient *in the specific case at hand*, but only because `$a2` and `$a3` happen not to contain elements that aren't also in `$a1`.

Therefore, the *more general solution* is to use filter `Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<='`, because it limits the results to objects missing from the LHS (`$a1`), and not also vice versa.</sup>

**If the input arrays are NOT SORTED**:

Explicitly sorting the input arrays before comparing them greatly enhances performance:

```
(Compare-Object ($a1 | Sort-Object) ($a2 + $a3 | Sort-Object) | 
   Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=').InputObject
```

---

The following example, which uses a 10,000-element array, illustrates the difference in performance:

```
$count = 10000                     # Adjust this number to test scaling.
$a1 = 0..$($count-1)               # With 10,000: 0..9999
$a2 = 0..$($count/2)               # With 10,000: 0..5000
$a3 = $($count/2+1)..($count-3)    # With 10,000: 5001..9997

$(foreach ($pass in 1..2) {

  if ($pass -eq 1 ) {
    $passDescr = "SORTED input"
  } else {
    $passDescr = "UNSORTED input"
    # Shuffle the arrays.
    $a1 = $a1 | Get-Random -Count ([int]::MaxValue)
    $a2 = $a2 | Get-Random -Count ([int]::MaxValue)
    $a3 = $a3 | Get-Random -Count ([int]::MaxValue)
  }

  [pscustomobject] @{
    TestCategory = $passDescr
    Test = "CompareObject, explicitly sorted first"
    Timing = (Measure-Command {
        (Compare-Object ($a1 | Sort-Object) ($a2 + $a3 | Sort-Object) | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=').InputObject |
        Out-Host; '---' | Out-Host
    }).TotalSeconds
  },
  [pscustomobject] @{
    TestCategory = $passDescr
    Test = "CompareObject"
    Timing = (Measure-Command {
        (Compare-Object $a1 ($a2 + $a3) | Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=').InputObject |
        Out-Host; '---' | Out-Host
    }).TotalSeconds
  },
  [pscustomobject] @{
    TestCategory = $passDescr
    Test = "!.Contains(), two-pass"
    Timing = (Measure-Command {
        $a2AndA3 = $a2 + $a3
        $a1 | Where-Object { !$a2AndA3.Contains($_) } | 
        Out-Host; '---' | Out-Host
    }).TotalSeconds
  },
  [pscustomobject] @{
    TestCategory = $passDescr
    Test = "!.Contains(), two-pass, explicitly sorted first"
    Timing = (Measure-Command {
        $a2AndA3 = $a2 + $a3 | Sort-Object
        $a1 | Sort-Object | Where-Object { !$a2AndA3.Contains($_) } | 
        Out-Host; '---' | Out-Host
    }).TotalSeconds
  },
  [pscustomobject] @{
    TestCategory = $passDescr
    Test = "!.Contains(), single-pass"
    Timing = (Measure-Command {
        $a1 | Where-Object { !($a2 + $a3).Contains($_) } |
        Out-Host; '---' | Out-Host
    }).TotalSeconds
  },
  [pscustomobject] @{
    TestCategory = $passDescr
    Test = "-notcontains, two-pass"
    Timing = (Measure-Command {
        $a2AndA3 = $a2 + $a3
        $a1 | Where-Object { $a2AndA3 -notcontains $_ } |
        Out-Host; '---' | Out-Host    
    }).TotalSeconds
  },
  [pscustomobject] @{
    TestCategory = $passDescr
    Test = "-notcontains, two-pass, explicitly sorted first"
    Timing = (Measure-Command {
        $a2AndA3 = $a2 + $a3 | Sort-Object
        $a1 | Sort-Object | Where-Object { $a2AndA3 -notcontains $_ } |
        Out-Host; '---' | Out-Host    
    }).TotalSeconds
  },
  [pscustomobject] @{
    TestCategory = $passDescr
    Test = "-notcontains, single-pass"
    Timing = (Measure-Command {
        $a1 | Where-Object { ($a2 + $a3) -notcontains $_ } |
        Out-Host; '---' | Out-Host    
    }).TotalSeconds
  } 
}) |
  Group-Object TestCategory | ForEach-Object {
    "`n=========== $($_.Name)`n"
    $_.Group | Sort-Object Timing | Select-Object Test, @{ l='Timing'; e={ '{0:N3}' -f $_.Timing } }
  }
```

Sample output from my machine (output of missing array elements omitted):

```
=========== SORTED input


Test                                            Timing
----                                            ------
CompareObject                                   0.068
CompareObject, explicitly sorted first          0.187
!.Contains(), two-pass                          0.548
-notcontains, two-pass                          6.186
-notcontains, two-pass, explicitly sorted first 6.972
!.Contains(), two-pass, explicitly sorted first 12.137
!.Contains(), single-pass                       13.354
-notcontains, single-pass                       18.379

=========== UNSORTED input

CompareObject, explicitly sorted first          0.198
CompareObject                                   6.617
-notcontains, two-pass                          6.927
-notcontains, two-pass, explicitly sorted first 7.142
!.Contains(), two-pass                          12.263
!.Contains(), two-pass, explicitly sorted first 12.641
-notcontains, single-pass                       19.273
!.Contains(), single-pass                       25.174
```

- While timings will vary based on many factors, you can get a sense that **`Compare-Object` scales much better, *if the input is either pre-sorted or sorted on demand***, and the performance gap widens with increasing element count.
- **When *not* using `Compare-Object`, performance can be *somewhat* increased - but *not being able to take advantage of sorting* is the fundamentally limiting factor**:

  - Neither `-notcontains` / `-contains` nor `.Contains()` can take full advantage of presorted input.
  - *If* the input is *already sorted*: Using the `.Contains()` `IList` interface .NET *method* rather than the PowerShell `-contains` / `-notcontains` operators (which an earlier version of k7s5a's answer used) improves performance.
  - Joining arrays `$a2` and `$a3` *once, up front*, and then using the joined array in the pipeline improves performance (that way, the arrays don't have to be joined in every iteration).